# Problem with my block diagram: Error 5002 occurred at Init.vi

Tags: arduino, labview

I'm making a heart rate analyze, but I'm having a real problem with that. When I'm press to start the programm doesn't work, so, I've press to stop the running program and it shows me in the section where it's ready to close or finish the connection:

> Error 5002 occurred at Init.vi.  Unable to establish connection with
>   Arduino.  Please ensure that you have selected the correct COM port
>   and that you have flashed the Arduino with the correct firmware.
>
> This error code is undefined. Undefined errors might occur for a
>   number of reasons. For example, no one has provided a description for
>   the code, or you might have wired a number that is not an error code
>   to the error code input.
>
> Additionally, undefined error codes might occur because the error
>   relates to a third-party object, such as the operating system or
>   ActiveX. For these third-party errors, you might be able to obtain a
>   description of the error by searching the Web for the error code
>   (5002) or for its hexadecimal representation (0x0000138A).

This is my VI diagram:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

And this is my control panel:

[image: Control panel]

And the connections to my arduino:
[image: Arduino]

So:

1. how can I solve this problem?
2. Where can I find more information to get this

Thanks for your help, but I'm new on this world (Arduino and Labview)

Comment: FYI, error codes in the 5000-8000 range are third-party toolkits... not core language errors and not even NI libraries. There are other reserved ranges, but that’s the range most toolkits use. That means if you can’t get help here, contacting the device driver’s author is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the second and third paragraphs of that error message; they're generated because the Arduino VI's you're using are generating a custom error code that they haven't registered with the LabVIEW development environment, so its automated error handling doesn't know what they mean. The information you need is in the first paragraph though.

As [kosist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53441443/24447) says, the first thing to check is that you can communicate with the Arduino at all. Before you even start with LabVIEW, have you tried using the Arduino IDE to program your device with a simple program like the 'blink' example?

If that works, then the next step is to make sure you've programmed your Arduino with the firmware it needs to communicate with the LabVIEW VIs you're using (can you link to where you got them from?) and then try a much simpler test program in LabVIEW - again, just get the Arduino to do something simple like turn the buzzer on and off. If you hit a problem with any of those, I suggest asking a new question with details of exactly what you tried and what errors you saw.

Comment: Hi, yes. I've done that on the IDE for arduino, and I can have access to him, with the serial plotter and I can have access to the buzzer from the arduino... and the real problem it's the connection, with a simple labview programm I can't have access.

Comment: OK, so the next step is the Arduino firmware. To receive commands and return data to and from the 'Arduino' VIs in the LabVIEW program, the Arduino must be running some code that understands and responds to those commands. Have you uploaded that to the Arduino?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the suggestion given in error message. First of all, make sure that you could communicate with Arduino using some simple serial line terminal, like [RealTerm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/), or [HTerm](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/). In case if you couldn't send any command using serial line terminal, check out which firmware do you have on Arduino. 
This is the way, how you could troubleshoot this issue...